# Sumar valores agrupados y sumados previamente

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

```
SELECT   Vd.ID_Vendedor, Ve.ID_Venta,
         COALESCE(SUM(Costo) * (1-(SUM(Descuento)/COUNT(Descuento)/100)), SUM(Costo)) Monto_Total

FROM     LibroVersion V, Detalle_Ventas D, Ventas Ve, Vendedores Vd 

WHERE    V.ISBN = D.ISBN AND D.ID_Venta = Ve.ID_Venta AND Ve.ID_Vendedor = Vd.ID_Vendedor

GROUP BY Vd.ID_Vendedor, Ve.ID_Venta

ORDER BY 1;
```

En este código tengo como resultado el identificador vendedor, junto al identificador de ventas, de tal manera que se puede apreciar las ventas que ha realizado cada vendedor. En la tercer columna se encuentra el monto total de cada venta.
Lo que busco hacer es poder agrupar por ID_Vendedor y de esta forma alcanzar a sumar lo que ha vendido en total cada uno de los vendedores en cuestión de dinero. Intenté realizar un SUM a la tercer columna (La del monto total) sin embargo salta un error de que no existe una agrupación singular de la función GROUP

Aquí está el resultado de la consulta que realicé:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ejemplo, me gustaría que el valor 1 de ID_Vendedor solo apareciera una vez y nos mostrara el Monto_Total de este que sería 2571.2025

Es importante mencionar que cada venta tiene su propio descuento y en ocasiones este resulta ser 0 (Null), por eso use COALESCE y la operación de (SUM(Descuento)/COUNT(Descuento)/100) para calcular el monto de cada venta fue para poder usar el descuento una sola vez (Ya que al ser agrupado este podía llegar a repetirse)

La imagen de la BD es la siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener un resultado *resumido* por vendedor, quita el `id_venta` de los resultados y agrupa solamente por vendedor:

```
SELECT   Vd.ID_Vendedor
       , COALESCE(SUM(Costo) * (1-(SUM(Descuento)/COUNT(Descuento)/100)), SUM(Costo)) Monto_Total
FROM     LibroVersion V, Detalle_Ventas D, Ventas Ve, Vendedores Vd 
WHERE    V.ISBN = D.ISBN AND D.ID_Venta = Ve.ID_Venta AND Ve.ID_Vendedor = Vd.ID_Vendedor
GROUP BY Vd.ID_Vendedor
ORDER BY 1;
```

Dicho esto, recomiendo que dejes de hacer *joins implícitos*, que era la forma de hacer *join* hace 30 años. El estándar SQL de 1992 (si, 1992) introdujo la sintaxis de `join` explícito y una vez te pasas a ella no vuelves la vista atrás.

Tiene mucho más claridad, es un estándar soportado por distintos motores y separa las condiciones que *unen* unas tablas con otras, de las condiciones que *filtran* resultados de la consulta (entre otras ventajas).

La misma consulta, haciendo uso de esta sintaxis, luciría más o menos así:

```
SELECT   Vd.ID_Vendedor
       , COALESCE(SUM(Costo) * (1-(SUM(Descuento)/COUNT(Descuento)/100)), SUM(Costo)) Monto_Total
FROM     LibroVersion V
         inner join Detalle_Ventas D on V.ISBN = D.ISBN
         inner join Ventas Ve on D.ID_Venta = Ve.ID_Venta
         inner join Vendedores Vd on Ve.ID_Vendedor = Vd.ID_Vendedor
GROUP BY Vd.ID_Vendedor
ORDER BY 1;
```

Finalmente, sospecho que la tabla `LibroVersion` está de más en la consulta, dado que no calificas los campos y no sé de donde viene cada uno, no la quité, pues puede que algún campo saliera de ella, aunque en un buen modelo, diría que no.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, pero el problema es que al hacer eso mezclamos los descuentos y me da resultados que no tienen que ver con la realidad, poruqe como ya dije, el vendedor de ID 1 tiene que ganar 2571.2025, pero con esta solución gana 2367, necesito cambiar mi algoritmo, pero no sé cómo

Comment: Esta consulta no puede dar un resultado diferente del que daría hacer la suma a mano de las líneas que devuelve la consulta que pusiste en la pregunta. Si da el resultado incorrecto, el problema está en esa consulta de origen.